# altering a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix ('data') which is composed of day of year in the first column and temperature data in the second column and also a vector ('dDates') of values which also represent day of year. e.g.

```
clear all 
n = 366;
day = linspace(1+1/24,n,(n-1)*24)';
temp = rand(8760,1);
data = [day,temp];
dDates = [12, 32, 45, 67];
```

I'm trying to alter 'data' so that it only contains data which is measured for the 120 rows following the day number specified in 'dDates' although being the same size as the original 'data' i.e. the other rows filled with nans.

Each measurement in 'data' refers to one hour so 120 refers to 5 days worth of data.

So far I have used:

```
[r,c,v] = find(data(:,1)>dDates(1),1,'first');
```

inside a loop to find the row number of each element of 'dDates' in 'dates' but am finding it difficult to bring everything together to produce the outcome that I need. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot going on here so I made several changes. Generating `data` can be done avoiding the LINSPACE command. Also, the temperature data is initialized to NaN:

```
>> n = 366;
>> data = [(1:1/24:(n-1/24))' ones(8760, 1)*NaN];
```

You can avoid using a loop to find the start indices of each date of interest by calculating the start indices since the date column in `data` is evenly spaced in time:

```
>> dDates = [12 32 45 67];
>> startIndex = (dDates - 1) * 24 + 1;
```

Verify that this worked:

```
>> data(startIndex)

ans =

    12    32    45    67
```

Generate the random temperature data for the dates of interest:

```
>> temp = rand(120*length(dDates), 1);
```

Determine the indices into `data` that correspond to the start dates of interest and the following 120 records:

```
>> targetIndex = repmat((0:119)', 1, length(dDates)) + repmat(startIndex, 120, 1);
```

Slot the random data into the target locations:

```
>> data(targetIndex, 2) = temp;
```

Verify that this worked:
[image]